# Values changed in inputs on one tab are echoed and overwrite values on other tabs

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I've got an MVC CORE/Entity Framework CORE project with some Razor pages.   On the Razor pages, if I've got the same page open in two tabs/browsers, changing the inputs on one, change the inputs on the other.  So, if in one tab I'm editing book 345

http://localhost:12345/books/edit/345

and in another I'm editing 456

http://localhost:12345/books/edit/456

if I'm editing the `Title` text box on 345, as I type, the same values are echoed on the `Title` text box on 456.   The same is true for all inputs, drop downs, text/numeric input boxes, checkboxes, etc.   Saving commits whatever's in the inputs to the record.

Any ideas why?   I've not added any code as I'm not sure which'd be most relevant and don't want to dump the entire project here.

**Edited for code based on comments**

```
private readonly MyModels.MyContext _context;
public EditModel(MyModels.MyContext context) : base(context) {
    _context = context;
}
[BindProperty]
public BookModel objRecord { get; set; }
```

This is the top of the Razor page's code behind, with the constructor and bound property

```
@page "{BookID?}"
@model myProject.Pages.Books.EditModel
```

This is the top of the .cshtml page.

Comment: Do you have your model in the sessionstorage?

Comment: I'm not using anything that fancy, I've just got the code I've added to the question to link the page to the record.

Comment: Do you have Browser Link turned on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? How did you create the razor page.

Comment: Created a new project, added EF for a model, added razor page to edit, totally boilerplate, nothing fancy, no JavaScript involved, it's bizarre.

Comment: Try to check how to reproduce your issue with [CoreRazor](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3iTUo74lMRztVxybJ?e=jYz9ov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `startup.cs`

in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ForceGateway.Models.ForceGatewayContextModel contextM) {
```

I've got

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseBrowserLink();
```

`UseBrowserLink` links browsers to each other as well as to Visual Studio t'would appear.